# Exception HandlerMethodArgumentResolversHolder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-integration, spring-cloud

Not able to up the application getting this below exception.

While trying to upgrade Java and spring Boot parent starter

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration.bindingService
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/config/HandlerMethodArgumentResolversHolder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.config.HandlerMethodArgumentResolversHolder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml has upgraded spring boot parent starter and Java

Do i need to add any other Maven dependency for that?

Tried adding spring-integration-core dependency leads to different exception.

```
<parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.9</java.version>
            <springfox.version>2.6.0</springfox.version>
        </properties>


    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>

         </dependency>

            <!-- Circuit Breaker -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-circuit-breaker</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Registry & Discovery -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- For Config Server -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- spring reactor -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.3</version>
            </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Excel Generation -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
                <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--Common jar dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
                <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency> -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>Finchley.SR2</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

            </project>
```

Comment: Q: Did updating (yet again) Spring Cloud/Spring Boot help?  Q: If so, which versions did you wind up using?

Answer (score 12):

You should upgrade your spring-cloud to `Greenwich.RELEASE`. You currently pulling `Finchley.SR2` which pulls wrong stream and SI dependencies that are incompatible with Spring Boot 2.1.x

Comment: if i keep Greenwich.RC2. getting dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar is missing. @ line 102, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar is missing. @ line 108, column 15

Comment: I would recommend raising the eureka question in `spring-cloud` channel. I know there was something going on with netflix stuff but not quite sure what.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me as Finchley was not compatible with 2.1.4

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the problem:

> [Issue #1521 Incompatibility with spring-integration-core 5.1.0](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1521)
>
> This problem reproduced when spring-boot upgrade from 2.0.6 to 2.1.0
>   (spring-integration version also updated)
>
> ...
>
> This is a known issue and there is nothing we can do other then to
>   ensure that a particular release of SCSt works with a particular
>   releases of other libraries. What complicates this case is that as you
>   can see from the stack trace, this particular incompatibility is
>   completely unrelated to spring-cloud-stream, rather spring-boot. Also,
>   we've just released spring-cloud-stream 2.1.0.RC1 which is build on
>   boot 2.1.0.RELEASE. It uses SI 5.1.0.RELEASE. -
>   https://spring.io/blog/2018/10/30/spring-cloud-stream-fishtown-rc1-2-1-0-rc1-release-announcement
>
> So I am closing this issue.

Here's a similar issue (also a Spring Boot upgrade, also on Spring Cloud):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15088

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Try building against a different version of Spring Boot.
2. If it works, please post back what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issued by below version

```
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR8")
}
```